# Log.println() method with Log.DEBUG and Log.VERBOSE not working in Nokia 1

Tags: android-studio, adb, android-logcat, nokia

I have checked and found that Log.println() method with Log.INFO is printing in logcat, but other mode is not working for Nokia 1.

I have already

(a) factory reset the phone,

(b) turn off the developer option and restart my phone,

(c) check for any logging option to be turned on

(d) increase logger buffer sizes to 1 M per log buffer

But nothing has any effect!

- What is the problem with my device?
- How to fix the problem?

Comment: Nooooo! Just stumbled upon your question and how sad there are no answers... Did you figure out a way to do this?

Comment: same here, I don't know what to do with Nokia 1

Comment: I am facing the same. did you figure out a way to resolve this?

Comment: Not yet! Please inform me if you find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#isLoggable(java.lang.String,%20int)

> The default level of any tag is set to INFO. This means that any level above and including INFO will be logged. You can change the default level by setting a system property: 'setprop log.tag. '

E.g. adb shell setprop log.tag.MyTag DEBUG

Comment: can you please elaborate? Which system property do I need to change? the phone?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, you run that command from command line of the computer which is connected to the phone.